# Global Variable in CountDownTimer not changing

Tags: java, android

Please assist, I have the following code that I have tried executing in diffirent places with the following results:
1) When placed in the on create it keeps resetting to 60 seconds
2) When placed in onResume it seems to work perfectly until the play again button is pressed then it starts counting down from the last onPause position
3) When placed in the playAgain method it crashes

Code:
createTimer Method

```
public void createTimer(){

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeRemaining, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {

                if (!isFinnish) {
                    timeRemaining = l;
                } else {

                    timeRemaining = 63200;
                }

                countDownText.setText(String.valueOf(l/1000-60));

                if (l <= 61000) {

                    timerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(l/1000) + "s");
                    button0.setEnabled(true);
                    button1.setEnabled(true);
                    button2.setEnabled(true);
                    button3.setEnabled(true);
                    button0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    sumTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    countDownText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                if (l/1000 == 30){

                    if (MainActivity.mplayer7 != null) {
                        MainActivity.mplayer7.release();
                        MainActivity.mplayer7 = null;
                    }

                    MainActivity.mplayer7 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.halfway);

                    if (MainActivity.muted == false) {

                        MainActivity.mplayer7.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
                    }

                    MainActivity.mplayer7.start();

                }


                if (l/1000 == 5){

                    if (MainActivity.mplayer != null) {
                        MainActivity.mplayer.release();
                        MainActivity.mplayer = null;
                    }

                    MainActivity.mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ticktock);

                    if (MainActivity.muted == false) {

                        MainActivity.mplayer.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
                    }

                    MainActivity.mplayer.start();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                timerTextView.setText("0s");
                timeRemaining = 63200;
                isFinnish = true;

                //Log.i("Score", String.valueOf(score));
                //Log.i("Number of Questions", String.valueOf(numberOfQuestions));
                //Log.i("Percentage", String.valueOf(percentage));
                //resultTextView.setText("You scored: " + Integer.toString(score) + "/" + Integer.toString(numberOfQuestions));

                if (score > 0) {
                    percentage = score * 100 / numberOfQuestions;
                }
                else {
                    percentage = 0;
                }

                button0.setEnabled(false);
                button1.setEnabled(false);
                button2.setEnabled(false);
                button3.setEnabled(false);
                playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                returnToMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                resultDisplayTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                resultTextView.setText(" ");

                if (percentage > 80) {
                    resultDisplayTextView.setText("Fantastic Score! " + Integer.toString(percentage) + "%");

                    if (MainActivity.mplayer3 != null) {
                        MainActivity.mplayer3.release();
                        MainActivity.mplayer3 = null;
                    }

                    MainActivity.mplayer3 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.fireworks);

                    if (MainActivity.muted == false) {

                        MainActivity.mplayer3.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
                    }

                    MainActivity.mplayer3.start();

                }
                else if (percentage >= 60 && percentage < 80) {
                    resultDisplayTextView.setText("Great Score! " + Integer.toString(percentage) + "%");

                }
                else if (percentage >= 40 && percentage < 60) {
                    resultDisplayTextView.setText("Average Score! " + Integer.toString(percentage) + "%");

                }
                else if (percentage > 1 && percentage < 40) {
                    resultDisplayTextView.setText("Poor Score! " + Integer.toString(percentage) + "%");

                    if (MainActivity.mplayer4 != null) {
                        MainActivity.mplayer4.release();
                        MainActivity.mplayer4 = null;
                    }

                    MainActivity.mplayer4 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.poor);

                    if (MainActivity.muted == false) {

                        MainActivity.mplayer4.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
                    }

                    MainActivity.mplayer4.start();

                }
                else {

                    resultDisplayTextView.setText("You did not play?");

                    if (MainActivity.mplayer5 != null) {
                        MainActivity.mplayer5.release();
                        MainActivity.mplayer5 = null;
                    }

                    MainActivity.mplayer5 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.poor);

                    if (MainActivity.muted == false) {

                        MainActivity.mplayer5.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
                    }

                    MainActivity.mplayer5.start();
                }

            }
        };


    }
```

playAgain Method

```
public void playAgain (View view) {

        score = 0;
        isFinnish = false;
        numberOfQuestions = 0;
        timerTextView.setText("60s");
        pointsTextView.setText("0/0");
        resultTextView.setText("");
        playAgainButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        returnToMenu.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        resultDisplayTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        countDownText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        sumTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if (MainActivity.mplayer3 != null) {
            MainActivity.mplayer3.release();
            MainActivity.mplayer3 = null;
        }

        if (MainActivity.mplayer4 != null) {
            MainActivity.mplayer4.release();
            MainActivity.mplayer4 = null;
        }

        if (MainActivity.mplayer6 != null) {
                    MainActivity.mplayer6.release();
                    MainActivity.mplayer6 = null;
        }

        MainActivity.mplayer6 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.countdown);

        if (MainActivity.muted == false) {

            MainActivity.mplayer6.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
        }

        MainActivity.mplayer6.start();

        countDownTimer.start();

        generateQuestion();

    }
```

onCreate

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        createTimer();

        // THIS CODE IS TO ENABLE THE ICON IN THE TASKBAR ////////////////////
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // SET IT TO ONLY POTRAIT VIEW
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        countDownText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countDownText);
        playAgainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playAgainButton);
        returnToMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnToMenu);
        sumTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sumTextView);
        resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
        resultDisplayTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultDisplayTextView);
        pointsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pointsTextView);
        timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerTextView);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        linearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
        button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        MainActivity.mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

        MainActivity.mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ticktock);
        MainActivity.mplayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.pop);
        MainActivity.mplayer2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.wrong);
        MainActivity.mplayer3 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.fireworks);
        MainActivity.mplayer4 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.poor);
        MainActivity.mplayer5 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.poor);
        MainActivity.mplayer6 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.countdown);
        MainActivity.mplayer7 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.halfway);

        if (MainActivity.muted == false) {

            MainActivity.mplayer.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
            MainActivity.mplayer1.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
            MainActivity.mplayer2.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
            MainActivity.mplayer3.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
            MainActivity.mplayer4.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
            MainActivity.mplayer5.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
            MainActivity.mplayer6.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
            MainActivity.mplayer7.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);

        }

        MainActivity.displayAds();


        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                playAgain(playAgainButton);
            }
        }, 1000);

    }
```

onResume and onPause

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        countDownTimer.start();

        if (MainActivity.mAdView != null) {
            MainActivity.mAdView.resume();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        countDownTimer.cancel();

        if (MainActivity.mAdView != null) {
            MainActivity.mAdView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
```

I have the global var set and assumed that resetting it in the onFinnish within the countdown timer should reset it but it does not.

Thanks

Comment: Crashes with what exception ?

Comment: null pointer, I know the reason is because it calls the countDownTimer.start() before the createTimer(). I am just playing around to see where it is suppose to be. If the createTimer() is in the onResume all seems to work but it keeps the timeRemaining = l value when play again is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields (what you called Global vars) are are not guranteed to be restored on activity recreation and can be GC anytime. You should rather create var in on create, store them in `Bundle` `onPouse` and again recreate them from that `Bundle` in another `onCreate` or `onResume` methods.

Here you have Google Dev's docs about how to handle activity creation, recreation and finalization https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

So basicly 1) it resets to 60 secs because it is recreated everytime you get back to your activity (from diffrerent app aor different activity)
2) idk where is your "play again" thing and I am not going to go into that code
3) `countDownTimer.start();` probably here it crashes with NPE am i right? (I am reading my crystall ball right now)

Read the full Google's tutorial about acitivity lifecycle and you wont have any troubles fixing your code.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html